# grep case-insensitively for a string in a text file

Tags: linux, perl

I'm writing a Perl script but I don't get a part of it.

There's a text file with host names, one per line.

I need to search a second file with host names (a blacklist) for the hostname read from the first one. To be sage the search should be done case insensitive.

My first approach was using the Perl `grep`, but I read about it and it seems not quite usable for what I needed it to. So I  thought about using the shell `grep`.

As far as I know, it could be executed with `system`, `qx`, backticks and `open`.

I decided to use `system`, so that I can get the exit status code of the `grep` and use it in a `if` statement to do the rest of the work the script is intended to. My code looks like this (test script with the `grep`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $blacklist_server = "de9899svc";
my $server = undef;
my $exit_value = undef;

 open(SERVERLISTE,"/home/ansible/serverscan/scan_results/serverliste_22.02.17.txt") or die "$!";

OUTER: while (<SERVERLISTE>) {
    $server = $_;

    system("grep -i '\$server' /home/ansible/serverscan/black.list");
    $exit_value  = $? >> 8;
    print "$exit_value\n";
}

close SERVERLISTE;
```

The problem is, that `$exit_value` is always 1, regardless of whether the host names match or not. So can somebody please tell me what I'm missing :)

Comment: `if (grep{/$server/i} <SERVERLISTE>)` Please try in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 grep -iF -f blacklist serverlist
```

The above command prints all lines in `serverlist` that match any of the lines in `blacklist` case insensitively.

If you want to remove lines from `serverlist` that matches any line in `blacklist` use:

```
 grep -viF -f blacklist serverlist
```

You can grab output inside perl using back ticks.

```
$not_blacklisted=`grep -viF -f blacklist serverlist`;
```

More readable commands:

```
grep --ignore-case --fixed-strings --file=blacklist serverlist
```

or

```
grep --invert-match --ignore-case --fixed-strings --file=blacklist serverlist
```

I tried this with GNU grep 2.25.

Answer (score 4):

The better question would be to ask how to get Perl's `grep` to do what you wanted. It is almost always a better route to write Perl code instead of creating a whole new shell process to do something simple like this. I am certain it is possible, but I cannot correct your misconceptions if you don't explain

The problem is that you don't use `chomp` to remove the line endings from the records you read from either of the files. Putting a newline in the middle of a shell command will terminate the command at that point, so it looks like `grep -i '$server`

I would build a hash of blacklisted servers, and check it for each server in the list

The code would look something like this. It uses the case folding `fc` operator to compare case-insensitively, and so requires the feature to be enabled

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature qw/ fc say /;

use constant {
    SERVER_LISTE => '/home/ansible/serverscan/scan_results/serverliste_22.02.17.txt',
    BLACK_LISTE  => '/home/ansible/serverscan/black.list',
};

my %blacklist = do {
    open my $fh, '<', BLACK_LISTE or die $!;
    my @blacklist = <$fh>;
    chomp @blacklist;
    map { fc $_ => 1 } @blacklist;
};

open my $server_liste, '<', SERVER_LISTE or die $!;

while ( my $server = <$server_liste> ) {

    chomp $server;

    say "server $server is blacklisted" if $blacklist{ fc $server };
}
```

Comment: @Sobrique: Sorry, thanks for pointing that out. The duplicate keys were just for testing and I forgot to take them out. The structure is just an anonymous hash, so later occurrences of the same key override any preceding ones.

Comment: That looks good. Thank you very much! The background is, that I'm importing a list of servers in my Ansible-Tower database. The servers come from a scanning script that looks for Linux servers in a given subnet. But there are also hosts like network-switches, appliances etc. that are recognized as Linux hosts, but not manageable with Ansible. So I'm building a blacklist with this hosts and the import scripts needs to ignore this hosts. If you have a better idea about how to achieve this, I'm happy to hear it :)

Comment: The "BLACK_LISTE  => 'black.list'," is redundant, by the way :)

Comment: Ah okay. I think you should do *that* by adding a `blacklist` table to your database instead of keeping the list as a text file. Then you can just write `SELECT * FROM servers WHERE servers.name NOT IN ( SELECT name FROM blacklist )` or the equivalent.

Comment: That file name was a mistake. See my comment to **Sobrique** above. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Not a bad idea with the blacklist table. But I would have to combine it with the insert into. The new servers, that should be added to the db, are in the textfile. When they don't already exist in the db AND NOT in the blacklist, then they I want to add them to the db. It's a long time ago, that I've worked with SQL. Is it possible to combine this where clause you stated before with a insert into?

Comment: @audioslave: How about you just add *all* the new servers and then `DELETE FROM servers WHERE servers.name IN ( SELECT name FROM blacklist )`?

Comment: I've found a way:

`#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings 'all';


my $rv = qx(grep -iF -f /home/ansible/serverscan/black.list /home/ansible/serverscan/scan_results/serverliste_22.02.17.txt);

my @lines = split /\n/, $rv;`

This way all the hostnames that are new servers, but not in the blacklist, are stored in the array. From there I can add them to the DB. Thanks a lot to all of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in your code: $server contains a trailing "\n". You should chomp it. In the call to grep, you have a \ before the $.